# xsl if and xsl foreach where element value is

Tags: xslt, xpath

this is my xml:

```
<root>
 <a>
  <b>
   <t>1</t>
  </b>
  <b>
   <t>2</t>
  </b>
 </a>
</root>
```

i want to ask:  thats tell me if any t exist but i want true answer onky if b exsit and he have t=1

tanks

Comment: Good question (+1). See my answer for a short and efficient solution. :)

Answer (score 1):

The test you looking for is

```
//b/t[text() = '1']
```

This test can now be used in a `template` as the match, in a `for-each` loop as a selector or in a `if` statement as the test - e.g.:

```
<xsl:template match="//b/t[text() = '1']">
    <!-- all t children of b with a content of 1 -->
</xsl:template>

<xsl:for-each select="//b/t[text() = '1']">
    <!-- all t children of b with a content of 1 -->
</xsl:for-each>

<xsl:if test="//b/t[text() = '1']">
    <!-- This is the true case -->
</xsl:if>
```

**Note:**

- This post is based on the asumption that you query from the root level *and do not know where the b/t combination is*. If you query from a point deeper in the hierarchy *or know exactly the path to the b/t combination,* you <strike>might want</strike> should <strike>to</strike> replace `//` with something more appropriate *to avoid inefficiencies*.
- <strike>Also please note, that the `text()` function concatenates the textual content of all descendant nodes, i.e. only use it in the above way if you can be sure that there are no further descendants.</strike>
  The text() node-test returns all text nodes underneath the context node. (Martin, thanks for pointing this out).

Comment: Obalix, why do you say "that the text() function concatenates the textual content of all descendant nodes"? That is not correct. In your XPath expression `//b/t[text() = '1']` the predicate in square brackets is true for a "t" element if it has at least one text child node with contents "1". If you used `//b/t[. = '1']` then the string value of a "t" element is compared to "1" and the string value is the concatenation of all text node descendants.

Comment: 1. Using the `//` abbreviation in an XPath expression results in significant inefficiency. 2. Why have you provided syntactically illegal XSLT code?

Comment: @Dimitre Novatchev: For 1.: Agreed, see my note; For 2.: Out of stupidity, sorry, corrected the samples.

Comment: @Martin Honnen: Thanks, for pointing this out, I was unaware of this.

Answer (score 1):

**Use**:

```
boolean(/*/*/b[t=1])
```

**When evaluated against the provided XML document, the result is:**

```
true()
```

**Remember**: **Always try to avoid the `//` abbreviation**, because it causes extremely inefficient traversing of the whole (sub) tree rooted at the context node.